# How to wait for valid input

Tags: c++

I'm re-enacting a battle and it's based on a coin, heads or tails. I have the user input either "H,h,T,t" to determine the battle. My problem is I have implemented that those can only be the valid inputs, but if i enter "G", for example, it displays invalid input but still executes. How can i get my program to wait for one of these valid inputs? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    //A little information about the battle

    cout << "\t\t\tLet the\n\n";
    cout << "Decision of heads or tails on the coin react history\n";

    cout << "\t\t/---------------------\\" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t| RETURN TO SEVEN DAYS|\n";
    cout << "\t\t\\---------------------/\n\n" << endl;

    //Main Battle

    cout << "It is July 1, 1862, the final day\n";
    cout << "of the Battle of Seven Days...\n\n";

    cout << "In this re-enactment of the second day\n";
    cout << "of battle, you are George B. McClellan\n";
    cout << "in charge of the Unionists\n\n";

    cout << "We will flip a coin to determine the\n";
    cout << "outcome of the small battles for\n";
    cout << "territories within the Seven Days area\n\n";

    cout << "You will have to predict whether the coin\n";
    cout << "will come up heads or tails...\n\n";

    cout << "In the actual Battle at Seven Days,\n";
    cout << "the Northern troops turned back Lee's\n";
    cout << "final assaults at Malvern Hill(July\n";
    cout << "1)....\n\n";

    cout << "The confederates lost about 16,000\n";
    cout << "men...\n\n";

    cout << "The Unionists lost about 20,000 men...\n\n";

    cout << "McClellan's failure to capture\n";
    cout << "Richmond, and the subsequent\n";
    cout << "withdrawal of the Union's Army from\n";
    cout << "the Yorktown Peninsula, signified the\n";
    cout << "end of the Peninsular Campaign\n\n";

    //Running through the battles

    int battleName = 1;

    for (; battleName <= 9; battleName += 1){

        cout << "Battle \t\n" << battleName << " - ";

        switch (battleName)
        {
        case 1: cout << "Oak Grove ";
            break;
        case 2: cout << "Mechanicsville ";
            break;
        case 3: cout << "Gaines Mill ";
            break;
        case 4: cout << "Garnett Farm ";
            break;
        case 5: cout << "Golding Farm ";
            break;
        case 6: cout << "The Peach Orchard ";
            break;
        case 7: cout << "Savage Station ";
            break;
        case 8: cout << "Frayser Farm ";
            break;
        case 9: cout << "Malvern Hill ";
            break;
        }

        //Asking the user for input

        cout << "\nNow Now, General McClellan\n";
        cout << "What do you predict the coin outcome will be, \n";
        cout << "Heads (H) or Tails (T)? \n";
        cout << "Please choose either Heads or Tails:\n";

        string userInput;

        cin >> userInput;

        if (userInput == "H" || userInput == "h")
            cout << "\n You have chosen heads!" << endl;

        if (userInput == "T" || userInput == "t")
            cout << "\n You have chosen tails!" << endl;

        else if (!(userInput == "H" || userInput == "h" || userInput == "T" || userInput == "t"))
            userInput = 'H';
            cout << "Invalid input. You must choose either heads or tails!\n";

        cout << "\t\tPlease get ready to fight, General McClellan!!\n\n\n";


        //random number function

    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand (seed);

    //to integers, heads or tails

    const int MIN_VALUE = 0;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 1;
    int coin = 0;

        coin = (rand () % (MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE +1)) + MIN_VALUE;

    //Deciding the actual coin flip

    cout << "The result of the coin flip was ";

        if (coin == 0)
            cout << "heads!\n\n\n";

        if (coin == 1)
            cout << "tails!\n\n\n";


    //incrementing values of the winner

    int computerScore = 0;
    int score = 0;



    if(((userInput == "T" || userInput == "t") && coin == 1))
    {
        cout << "Well done, General \nMcClellan...\n You have defeated Lee!\n";
        score += 1;
    }

     else if(((userInput == "H" || userInput == "h") && coin == 0))
    {
        cout << "Well done, General \nMcClellan...\n You have defeated Lee!\n";
        score += 1;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "I am sorry, General\nMcClellan...\n But the battle goes to Lee!";
            computerScore += 1;

    }

        cout << "\n So far: McClellan " << score << " victories,\n" << "Lee " << computerScore << "\n\n\n";



    //Scoring

    if (score > computerScore)
            cout << "The results show that\n George B. McClellan\nwon the majority of the battles\nand is thus declared the victor\non July 1 1862.\n\n\n";

    if (score < computerScore)
        cout << "The results show that\nRobert E Lee\nwon the majority of the battles\nand is thus declared the victor\non July 1 1862\n\n\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it will display "invalid input" in all cases. This isn't python.

Answer (score 2):

here is simplest way, I would use char as input.
EDIT: char would not work in this case, it is one of those things I forget when coding in c++.

```
string userINput;
while ((cin >> userInput) != "H" && userInput != "h" &&
            userInput != "T" && userInput != "t");
```

then I would get rid of this code:

```
else if (!(userInput == "H" || userInput == "h" || userInput == "T" || userInput == "t"))
            userInput = 'H';
            cout << "Invalid input. You must choose either heads or tails!\n";
```

all together.

You have also a problem here you want to execute userInput = H and print message after else but you do not have {} so it should be like this in order to work:

```
  else if (!(userInput == "H" || userInput == "h" || userInput == "T" || userInput == "t")) {
            userInput = 'H';
            cout << "Invalid input. You must choose either heads or tails!\n";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! i added that code but i'm getting a few errors(H,h,T,t- not declared in the scope. also when running my program before, my win values weren't incrementing right for McClellen and Lee, when i chose heads or tails and the battle was fought. Could you help me fix this?

Comment: for some reason those errors went away but now it's giving me some weird errors :(

Comment: i figured out everything else and changed some things! Thanks for the edit! Everything is building without errors and running, however no input is being accepted. Is this a easy fix?

Comment: like no input is being accepted when H,h,T,t is entered which it should be, only no input should be accepted and display "invalid input" when input is anything other then those characters

Comment: Ok sorry got confused a bit, you notice that in my while loop `||` are replaced with `&&`, my logic was wrong.